# What is the 'smallest' offense to get life in prison in USA?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, sentencing

If I want to spend the rest of my life in a prison in the USA but want to cause the least damage possible, what should I do?

Comment: This question is some kind of dark humor. It's just a joke :D

Comment: How would you quantify level of damage? A second offense of LSD trafficking can carry life.

Comment: @user6726's suggestion seems promising, but since it requires a second offence, it suggests an interesting strategy, namely, to commit an offence that will get you no more than several months in the prison system you contemplate calling home.  Then you can decide whether you really want to spend the rest of your life there before you proceed.

Comment: Just an example i have. The Richard Reid (Shoe bomber) didn't hurt anyone. And he is now in prison for life, plus in solitary confinement. Look like terrorism is a good choice.

Comment: You could walk into a prison and kill yourself.  Of course, YOU would be greatly damaged.  Sorry, couldn't resist with your theme of dark humor.

Comment: Leaking government secrets could arguably get you life for doing negative damage.

Answer (score 1):

contempt of court can hold an indefinite sentence until you abide by the court's wishes.

There is currently (by currently I mean last time I looked up his status) a man in prison in Scotland for being naked and attending his court proceedings naked. He is known as the naked rambler as he likes to walk around the uk countryside naked.

So what I would suggest is lots of consecutive small sentences rather than a single life sentence